# Get Value from two form control and set it to one form control

Tags: angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

How could I set a value of form control after calculating from two form Control?
These controls are part of the same form group.  And the form group is dynamically added to the form array.

[image]

```
           this.purchaseForm = this.fb.group({
          purchases: this.fb.array([this.getPurchaseFormGroup()])
        });
      
      getPurchaseFormGroup(): FormGroup {
        const form = new FormGroup({
          itemName: new FormControl(''),
          itemQty: new FormControl(''),
          itemPrice: new FormControl(''),
          itemAmt: new FormControl('')
        });
        return form;
    
      }

public addItem() {
    const form = this.purchaseForm.get('purchases') as FormArray
    form.push(this.getPurchaseFormGroup());
  }
```

Comment: Did you considered using something like `combineLatest(c1.valueChanges, c2.valueChanges)` ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use two approaches:

1. Listen to form changes through `valueChanges` observable on every new form group you are pushing within the form array.
2. You could use input events to react to those changes (this could be the easier one).

First approach:

```js
getPurchaseFormGroup(): FormGroup {
  const form = new FormGroup({
    itemName: new FormControl(''),
    itemQty: new FormControl(''),
    itemPrice: new FormControl(''),
    itemAmt: new FormControl('')
  });
  // You could listen for the whole form or just the controls that 
  // you need for your calculation like this
  combineLatest([
    form.controls.itemQty.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(form.controls.itemQty.value)),
    form.controls.itemPrice.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(form.controls.itemPrice.value)),
  ]).pipe(
    filter(([itemQty, itemPrice]) => itemQty && itemPrice)
  ).subscribe(([itemQty, itemPrice]) => {
      form.get('itemAmt').setValue(itemPrice * itemQty);
  });

  // The filter pipe is for avoiding calculations with null initial values
  // The combine latest won't be triggered until al least the two controls
  // got modified, so considering the case you want to provide initial values
  // we use the startWith pipe in order to trigger the itemAmt change

  return form;
}
```

Make sure you do `unsubscribe` the combineLatest observable if one of this forms is deleted or the component gets destroyed, you might take a look at [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/subsink) npm package, we don't want memory leaks.

Second approach:

On your template I think you could have something like

```html
<form 
  *ngFor="let f of form.controls.purchases.controls" 
  [formGroup]="f">
  <input formControlName="itemName">
  <input formControlName="itemQty">
  <input formControlName="itemPrice">
  <input formControlName="itemAmt">
</form>
```

Just listen to those inputs you need to your calculation, with something like

```html
<form 
  *ngFor="let f of form.controls.purchases.controls" 
  [formGroup]="f">
  <input formControlName="itemName">
  <input 
    formControlName="itemQty"
    (input)="onQtyChange($event, f)">
  <input 
    formControlName="itemPrice"
    (input)="onPriceChange($event, f)">
  <input formControlName="itemAmt">
</form>
```

And on your `ts` file

```js
onQtyChange(e: InputEvent, f: FormGroup): void {
  const qty = (e.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
  const price = f.get('itemPrice').value;
  f.get('itemAmt').setValue(qty * price);
}

onPriceChange(e: InputEvent, f: FormGroup): void {
  const qty = f.get('itemQty').value;
  const price = (e.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
  f.get('itemAmt').setValue(qty * price);
}
```